# Should initializer-list constructor take its parameter by reference or value

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

I am wondering why STL library classes' list constructor takes the `initializer_list<>` parameter by value instead of by reference? What is the difference between pass by value and pass by reference here? Is there any disadvantage or pitfalls to pass by reference to an `initializer_list<>`?

Examples:

```
string (initializer_list<char> il);
vector (initializer_list<value_type> il, const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
set (initializer_list<value_type> il, const key_compare& comp = key_compare(), const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
```

**EDIT**: **Correct me if I am wrong.** After fiddling with these two ways of passing initializer_list, I found that if we pass by reference, there will not be conversions on the comma-separated elements to the `value_type` of the container:

```
StrVec vs = {"a", "an", "the"}; // fails because {"a", "an", "the"} is not of type initializer_list<string>
error: no matching function for call to ‘StrVec::StrVec(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
note: candidates are:
StrVec::StrVec(std::initializer_list<std::basic_string<char> >&)
```

`StrVec` is my class that basically tries to behave like `vector<string>`.
But if we pass by value, then each of { "a", "an", "the" } are used as initializers to copy initialize `initializer_list<string>`'s elements (converting construct from `const char*` to `string`).

Comment: initializer_list has references to the elements it "contains".

Comment: @DamiánMontenegro oh, so it is very cheap to pass by value then?

Comment: That's it! You are right.

Comment: As to your edit: That's because `{...}` creates a *temporary* `initializer_list`, and temporaries don't bind to non-const lvalue refs.

Comment: @T.C. Oh I see. If the constructor could have been declared to either take const ref to `initializer_list` or take a value, which one is a better choice? From your linked question, it seems since copy is very cheap (and possibly we might want to change the `initializer_list` argument?) we may as well pass by value. Is my understanding right?